# Automatic resume of suspended machine

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to configure machine in VMware Workstation to automatically resume from sleep? Either to respect whatever timeout was set from within the machine (using some tool perhaps?) or on the VMware level. I want to run some tests that include suspending the system but I want it to wake up by itself.

Both host and the VM are running Windows.

EDIT - I think I found (was told) a **SOLUTION**:
 This configuration option won't suspend the machine when it enters the standby mode and will wait for cmos timer or user input to wake it up.

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_special_acpi_guest.html

Comment: Some solutions for your problem include highly specific commands. Is your guest system Windows XP, 7, 2008 Server etc.?

Comment: @SvenS It's Windows 7 ATM but I'd like it to work for ~any~ version. I think that the problem is that VMware doesn't care about these requests/timeouts to wake up created from the guest.

Answer (score 0):

[Wake-On-LAN](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/131343)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista I found [this short How To](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t86.html). I did not test it though, just wanted to share this.

Note that it is not of any importance what task you start (in that How To cmd.exe is started and told to exit right away), any task set like this will wake a sleeping PC. Just set the trigger to your liking.

Again, I didn't test this on any Virtual Machines, I don't know if VMPlayer listens to the guest OS for any wakeup-requests.